# Would the AdminSDHolder security propegation affect group membership?

Tags: active-directory, groups

I'm having an issue where every time I add users to the Enterprise Admin group in AD they are shortly thereafter removed.  I have Domain Admin rights.  I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the AdminSDholder.  From what I understand though, that should only affect the security ACL on the actual enterprise admin group object, not the group membership.

I keep having to re-add myself and the other Domain Admins to the group in order to manage our child domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Enterprise Admins a restricted group?  If so, the group membership updates need to be performed using Group Policy Management Console.

Comment: Ahh ha.  I forgot to check there.  Thank you! The Enterprise Admin group was set as a restricted group in the Default Domain Policy.